# Unique constraint for values in different column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table that has a `key` and an `alternative key` column within the same table. If a value is set in the `key` column, it must not be used in the `alternative key` column and vice versa. `

For example, this should be valid:

```
-----------------------------
|   Key   | alternative Key | 
|---------|-----------------|
| Key_1   | NULL            |
| Key_2   | NULL            |
| Key_3   | Key_36          |
| Key_4   | NULL            |
| ...     | ...             |
-----------------------------
```

But this should not be allowed:

```
-----------------------------
|   Key   | alternative Key | 
|---------|-----------------|
| Key_1   | NULL            |
| Key_2   | NULL            |
| Key_3   | Key_1           |
| Key_4   | NULL            |
| ...     | ...             |
-----------------------------
```

The root of the problem is, that my system communicates with a PLC through these keys. However, there are some use-cases where the key we send to the PLC is different from the key we display on screen. The `key` is always displayed on screen, but if an `alternative key` is present, it is used for communication instead of the `key`.

Is it possible to prevent this using SQL constraints or do I need to handle this in my business logic? I am using a code-first approach with C# entities using entity framework core, if that makes a difference. **I don't want to change my data-model, if I don't have to.**

Comment: Can you change the data model? It appears that an almost equivalent way to model it would be to always store "the" key in the `Key` column and then use the second column to *reference* the original key that this row represents an alternative key for. E.g. the Key_3 row would then by `Key_3, NULL` and a new Key_36 row would be `Key_36, Key_3`.

Comment: You would probably to use a `TRIGGER` for this, if you had to maintain this design.

Comment: We generate our tables from C# entities using a code-first approach.Do you happen to know if .net core supports these kind of things?

Comment: *"Do you happen to know if .net core supports these kind of things?"* What is "these things"?

Comment: On the one hand keys that reference another key as @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned and triggers, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Certainly you could change your design in EF to cater for the slight shift in design, yes. As for triggers, personally, I don't know as I tend to avoid code-first; if our developers are coming to me it's *because* they need a T-SQL solution for something they can't do in EF.

Comment: This data model is flawed. The only solid way to resolve is to fix the data model that your key value is a single column "The key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me Codd".

Comment: @SeanLange I can't use a single column as i need both values if both are set. I'll restate the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with the above comments about correcting your data model. Some databases, e.g., Sql Server, support unique indexes on schema-bound views. A view like `Select Key From TheTable Union All Select AlternateKey From TheTable Where AlternateKey Is Not Null` could then enforce a unique constraint.

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't want to change the data-model and would prefer to use the one I mentioned, because it results in one entity and does not need an extra view or table to do such a simple task as use an alternative key if present.